# Capybara attach_file method not uploading a file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

When a user on our website wants to create a new Object, they are required to upload an XML file, which is then passed to a controller action using AJAX. The controller method parses attributes from the XML file and passes them back to the JavaScript, which then auto-populates most of the new Object form fields.

The HTML looks like this:

```
 <input type="file" name="upload_datafile" id="upload_datafile" accept=".xml">
```

The file is pulled from the file input using the following:

```
$("#upload_datafile").change(function() {    
     var file = $("#upload_datafile").prop("files")[0];
     ...
```

The Capybara test looks like this:

```
scenario 'upload file', js: true do    
     expect(page).to have_css '#upload_datafile'
     attach_file('upload_datafile', File.expand_path('spec/fixtures/files/valid.xml'))
     expect(page).to have_field 'name', with: 'Valid Object'
end
```

The 'name' field should be populated when 'valid.xml' is uploaded and has been parsed. Instead, our XML parser, which tries to read the file, throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
     undefined method 'read' for "undefined":String
```

I have tested this extensively manually and no error is thrown. The file path is also correct in the Capybara test. If I throw a breakpoint into the Capybara test I can manually upload a file in the browser and it will work just fine. It appears that Capybara is not uploading the file and and instead our JavaScript passes the string 'undefined' to the controller action because that's the result when trying to get the 0th file in the 'files' prop of the file input during the Capybara test.

Why isn't Capybara actually uploading the file and/or why isn't the file accessible through JavaScript?

Comment: what versions of capybara, selenium-webdriver, and firefox (or whatever browser you're using selenium-webdriver to control) are you using?

Comment: Capybara 2.5.0, Selenium-webdriver 2.48.1, Firefox 42.0, JRuby 1.7.16.1, and Rails 4.1.4.

Comment: hmmm -- I can't replicate the failure, you're not using some kind of JS file input widget to make file inputs styleable, look the same across different browsers, are you?

Comment: Nope, the only JS tied to that file input is what I have listed above. We also use Bootstrap, but it doesn't look like that adds any JS that would interfere with the file upload process. If I throw a breakpoint into the JavaScript and inspect the 'files' prop of the file input field after uploading a file manually everything works fine. We also use database_cleaner if that's pertinent. Adding js: true makes no difference.